# Initialize C array with struct

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

Is it possible to initialise an array of uint8_t with a struct?

What I want to achieve is something similar to:

```
#define BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT 1024    

struct Device {
  uint32_t address;
  uint32_t id;
};

const uint8_t bytes[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT] = (struct Device) {
  .address = 123,
  .id = 456,
};
```

The reason I want to do this it to get an easy overlay view of the content I write to the byte array. I simply want an easy interface to whatever first bytes I need for the information that is displayed by the structure.

If thats not possible, what's the closest thing to it?

Comment: first thing. why'd you want to do that?

Comment: So you essentially simply want to put the struct values into an array?

Comment: I updated the post with the reason. I'm using an embedded system where I reserve a bigger chunk of memory but want to initialise the part used for the structure in a simple way.

Comment: whatever the reason may be, you cannot have a value of `456` held by `uint8_t`

Comment: No, but that's not what I'm trying to do either. I'm trying to initialise the array using the struct initialiser. If this would work, then the uint32_t would be laid out over 4 uint8_t.

Comment: This question was interesting, which answer do you pick? or none?

Answer (score 3):

The standard way in C to overlay data types is by using unions:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #define BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT 1024    

    struct Device {
      uint32_t address;
      uint32_t id;
    };

    union Memory {
            uint8_t bytes[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT];
            struct Device devices[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT/sizeof(struct Device)];
    };

    const union Memory memory = {
            .devices = {
                    { .address = 123, .id = 30 },
                    { .address = 111, .id = 89 }
            }
    };

    int main(void)
    {
            unsigned i;

            for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                    printf("%d ", memory.bytes[i]);

            putchar('\n');

            return 0;
    }
```

,

```
$ ./a 
123 0 0 0 30 0 0 0 111 0 0 0 89 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside approaching this via a `union` (as proposed by *hdante* here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462808/694576) instead of trying:

```
const uint8_t bytes[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT] = (struct Device) {
  .address = 123,
  .id = 456,
};
```

do quick and dirty:

```
uint8_t bytes[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT] = {0};
*((struct Device *) bytes) = ((struct Device) {
  .address = 123,
  .id = 456,
});
```

or better do:

```
struct Device dev = {
  .address = 123,
  .id = 456,
};

uint8_t bytes[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT] = {0};

...

size_t size_dev = sizeof dev;
memcpy(bytes, &dev, size_dev);
```

Then inspect array `bytes` up to the `size_dev - 1`th element.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it then

```
static const uint8_t buffer[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT] = {
    0x7b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0xc8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

Comment: If you want to test it do `memcpy(&device, buffer, sizeof(struct Device));` and print the values to see they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I have to work with bag of structured bytes, I create a "view" struct/class that gives me some higher-level interface to a block of memory. Manual pointer arithmetic is usually too error prone to be repeated. Create a "memory view" structure and unit-test it properly.

```
struct memory_view {
    uint32_t *addr;
    uint32_t *id;
};

void view_init(struct memory_view *view, void *buf, size_t bufsz) {
    // TODO: validate buffer size using bufsz here
    view->addr = (uint32_t*)buf;
    view->id = (uint32_t*)(buf + sizeof(uint32_t));
}

struct memory_view view;
uint8_t buffer[LARGE_NUMBER];
view_init(&view, buffer, LARGE_NUMBER);

*view->addr = 0xDEADBEEF;
*view->id = 0xCAFEBABE;
```

You can see a similar technique in device drivers, when structures are initialized to access different hardware registers located in some memory region.

You could also get a buffer pointer, cast it to structure and try using this memory block as it were a structure. Doable, but memory alignment can bite you hard. Such code may or may not work, depending on compiler and system architecture.

Comment: You declare `void view_init(struct memory_view *view, void *buf, size_t bufsz)`, but call `view_init(&view, buffer)`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's typo. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe want to do something like that, even if the copy is not that necessary as `b_sample` is exactly what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Device dev;
struct Device {
  uint32_t address;
  uint32_t id;
};

int main(void) {
    //create an instance `sample.address=123` and `sample.id=456`
    dev sample = (dev) { 123, 456 };
    //convert dev pointer to byte pointer, so you loop through bytes
    uint8_t* b_sample = (uint8_t *)(&sample);
    //buffer for copy
    uint8_t* bytes[1024];

    int size = (int)(sizeof(dev)/sizeof(uint8_t)), i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        bytes[i] = b_sample[i];
        //see what values you copy
        printf("%x ", bytes[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/wE8dbBV1

If you want to divide the struct into `uint16_t` segments you can safely replace all `uint8_t` with `uint16_t`

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to using a `uint8_t byte[]` array. You can also make use of a struct utilizing a `bitfield` for each `addr` and `id`. You (may/may not) find it more convenient, but it does provide an easy way to keep the offset information associated with any give `addr/id` pair.

I don't believe there is a way to directly make use of struct type **Designated Initializers** to fill the `uint8_t byte` array. I think the closest full initialization would be with `memcpy`. I've included that in the example below. **Note**, there is nothing that prevents you from filling the `uint8_t byte` array with `memcpy`, but then you have to track the `offset` within the `uint8_t byte` array to accurately point to any given byte in either `addr` or `id` for any given element. This is where the bitfield makes things a little easier. You get a **one-to-one** correlation between the `struct Device` index and the `uibitfield` index with `a1..4` and `b1..4` being the bytes within each `addr` and `id`, respectively.

A version using the `uint8_t` array is shown below this version.

Here is a short example with test data in an array of `struct Device`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct                      /* bitfield corresponding to struct Device */
{
    unsigned int  a1 : 8,
                  a2 : 8,
                  a3 : 8,
                  a4 : 8;

    unsigned int  b1 : 8,
                  b2 : 8,
                  b3 : 8,
                  b4 : 8;

} uibitfield;

struct Device {                     /* original struct Device   */
    uint32_t addr;
    uint32_t id;
};

int main () {

    /* test data in an array of struct Device   */
    struct Device dev[] = { {0x4009f0, 0}, {0x4009f1, 1}, {0x4009f2, 2}, {0x4009f3, 3}, 
                            {0x4009f4, 4}, {0x4009f5, 5}, {0x4009f6, 6}, {0x4009f7, 7}, 
                            {0x4009f8, 8}, {0x4009f9, 9}, {0x4009fa, 10}, {0x4009fb, 11}, 
                            {0x4009fc, 12}, {0x4009fd, 13}, {0x4009fe, 14}, {0x4009ff, 15}, 
                            {0x400a00, 16}, {0x400a01, 17}, {0x400a02, 18}, {0x400a03, 19} };

    int it = 0;                             /* general iterator */
    size_t sz = sizeof (dev)/sizeof (*dev); /* size of array    */

    /* create validate and fill bitfield array */
    uibitfield *bytes = calloc (sz, sizeof (*bytes));
    if (!bytes) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy (bytes, dev, sz * sizeof (dev));

    /* print bytes in each addr & id in dev */
    for (it = 0; it < sz; it++)
        printf ("\n  addr[%2d]:  0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x\n    id[%2d]:  0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x\n",
                it, (bytes + it)->a1, (bytes + it)->a2, (bytes + it)->a3, (bytes + it)->a4,
                it, (bytes + it)->b1, (bytes + it)->b2, (bytes + it)->b3, (bytes + it)->b4);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/memview

  addr[ 0]:  0xf0, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00
    id[ 0]:  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

  addr[ 1]:  0xf1, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00
    id[ 1]:  0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

  addr[ 2]:  0xf2, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00
    id[ 2]:  0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

  addr[ 3]:  0xf3, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00
    id[ 3]:  0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

  addr[ 4]:  0xf4, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00
    id[ 4]:  0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

  (snip)
```

**Note:** it was a unclear how you would be using/filling `struct Device` and how much of an initial peek you wanted at the data in `stuct Device`, so this is just intended as an example of viewing the data.

---

**using  a uint8_t byte array:**

If you do want to use the `uint8_t array, the changes needed are minimal:

```
    /* using  a uint8_t byte array    */
    uint8_t *bytearr = calloc (sz * 4, sizeof (*bytearr));
    if (!bytearr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy (bytearr, dev, sz * sizeof (dev));

    /* print bytes in each addr & id in dev using uint8_t array */
    for (it = 0; it < sz * 4; it+=8)
        printf ("\n  addr[%2d]:  0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x\n    id[%2d]:  0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x\n",
                it, bytearr[it], bytearr[it+1], bytearr[it+2], bytearr[it+3],
                it, bytearr[it+4], bytearr[it+5], bytearr[it+6], bytearr[it+7]);
```

**output is the same**

Answer (score 0):

Does this:

```
#define BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT 1024    

struct Device {
  uint32_t address;
  uint32_t id;
};

struct DeviceAndData {
  struct Device d;
  char filler[BIGGER_THAN_STRUCT - sizeof(Device)];
};
const struct DeviceAndData bytes_pre = { .d = { .address = 123, .id = 456 } };
const uint8_t* bytes = (uint8_t*)&bytes_pre;
```

do the trick? :)